# Is the sender name/signature on the bottom of a letter called 'inscription'?

Tags: word-usage

My attorney drafted some legal document for me but the name on the bottom of the letter was misspelled. When she asked me which part of the letter needs correction over email, I wanted to answer with a single precise noun (phrase). I looked up dictionary from my mother language to English and got the word 'inscription'. However, when I looked it up in English-to-English dictionaries, it seems not the proper word. Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line at the bottom of a legal document is called the [Signature Line](http://books.google.ca/books?id=-2XN0oDN_HgC&lpg=PA15&ots=tdYo1UhkiC&dq=name%20at%20bottom%20of%20legal%20documents&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=signature&f=false) and it includes your name.